# Text / formulas with shadows

Tags: shadows

On a website I've seen awesome formulas:

[image: http://www.jagemann-net.de/alkanole/files/etherbildung.png]
<sub>(source: [jagemann-net.de](http://www.jagemann-net.de/alkanole/files/etherbildung.png))</sub>

Is there any possibility to make

1. **shaded** text or
2. even **shaded** formulas? I know chemfig, but i haven't found a possibility for shading

with LaTeX / XeLaTex

Comment: Not to detract you from making these, but beware that text shadows often look terrible in print, and use quite a lot of ink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the shadowtext package, which I didn't try. But I guess for the website some post-processing was used.

E.g. have a look at how you can do that with ImageMagick:
http://www.macinchem.org/applescript/imagemagick.php

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried the shadowtext package, which works with chemfig too.
In order to get blurred shadows like in the example above you need post-processing, thanks for the link, this website was verhy helpful.